# Laravel Blade - section renders in the wrong place

Tags: php, html, laravel, templates, laravel-blade

I'm new to Laravel and i'm not quite sure yet how everything works.
I can't figure out how to properly manage templates. Now included section `inc.post` renders on top of everything else in parent template. Here's my code:

```
## layouts/base.blade.php

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- meta tags -->
</head>
<body>
@include('inc.navPanel')

@yield('content')

<footer class="container">
    <hr>
    <p>&copy; iCal Network 2020-2021</p>
</footer>

<!-- scripts -->

@yield('javascript')

</body>
</html>
```

Next file:

```
## home.blade.php

@extends('layouts.base')

@section('title')Home@endsection

@section('content')
    <!-- some html -->

            @foreach($posts as $post)
                @include('inc.post', ['post' => $post])
            @endforeach

    <!-- some html -->

@endsection

@section('javascript')
    <!-- scripts -->
@endsection
```

Included file:

```
## inc/post.blade.html

@section('post')
    <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ $post->title }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{!! Str::limit($post->text, 120) !!}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted clearfix">
            <div class="float-md-start">Author: {{ $post->user->name }}</div>
            <div class="float-md-end">{{ $post->created_at->isoFormat('DD.MM.YYYY в hh:mm') }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Included navbar that goes under the posts:

```
## inc/navPanel.blade.php

@section('navigation')
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <!-- navbar content -->
    </nav>
```

Comment: You're missing an `@endsection` in `inc/post.blade.php` to close the `@section('post')`.

Comment: @TimLewis, that way posts don't show up at all

Comment: You can remove `@section('post')`, it doesn't make any sense to have it in a loop. Notice that you don't have an `@yield` for it, as it would have to be placed within `home.blade.php`, which is a view and not a layout.

Comment: @user2094178  Yes, you're right, that's it, thank you. Thanks to a tutorial I thought this is a necessary syntax for any included content.